# how i can solve this question using while loop? i try but i did not able to break down

Tags: python, python-3.x

i dont undertand this question try to self learn python:

Write a program that reads whole numbers typed by the user until a negative number
is entered, then prints the number of even numbers that were entered.. Sample run:

```
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: 7
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 2
Enter a number: 9
Enter a number: -1
3 even numbers were entered
```

i am sure that i am doing something wrong

```
n = int(input("Enter a number : "))
while 0 < n :
    if 0 < n:
        n = int(input("Enter a number : "))
```

sorry i am new here dont know very much

Comment: Could you show what you've tried that doesn't work? Are you having troubles taking numbers as input or perhaps determining if a number is even... If you show what you've tried it may be someone can advise what you need to do to fix it

Comment: There is no [tag:python] in the question. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [ask] and how to create a [mcve] for ideas of how to write a good question.

Comment: Share what you tried, then ask questions about that. You won't learn anything by finding out there are people here that can do it. Also, there's millions of tutorials and guides out there that explain examples, perhaps start with those if you really need to be shown some basic examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out a few things:

- how to read input typed by the user.
- how to know whether it's a negative number
- how to know whether it's an even number
- how to keep count of numbers entered
- how to repeat functionality until some condition is met
- how to print results

None of these things is impossible to find out by looking at the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/), or indeed by [searching Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=).